# MFC/C++: Need distant "wall clock" time without resetting my system's time

Tags: c++, time, mfc

My ultimate goal is to know the integer number of hours between the current local ("wall clock") time (in New York) and the same in London. I am in New York.
I've read thru the MSDN documentation on "TimeZone" structures available to me. The complication is Daylight Time. I would appreciate code that would return "if" Daylight Savings time in a different city than where my system's clock is set. For example, today it is Daylight Time in New York but not (yet) Daylight Time in London, so I would wish to ultimately know "4 hours." For most of the year, it is 5 hours.
I can't take the route to transiently set my system time to British Time and then difference/read the "Daylight Time" status, yes/no, as my app has many concurrent threads that are extremely "wall clock"-sensitive and would go haywire if the system time were suddenly advanced a few hours, even if for but a few milliseconds. Instead, a 0/1 for current local Standard/Daylight (which I can do myself) and a 0/1 for distant (London) Standard/Daylight (which I need help with) would suffice. Or, of course, simply knowing the local time a system in London would display having elected to make the Daylight adjustment.

I am a relative beginner to C++. My development environment is Win7:VS2013:C++:MFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date (works on VS-2013):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tz.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zLondon   = locate_zone("Europe/London");
    auto zNew_York = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    auto diff = floor<hours>(zLondon->to_local(sys_days{2016_y/mar/21}) -
                           zNew_York->to_local(sys_days{2016_y/mar/21}));
    std::cout << diff.count() << "h\n";

    diff = floor<hours>(zLondon->to_local(sys_days{2016_y/jun/21}) -
                      zNew_York->to_local(sys_days{2016_y/jun/21}));
    std::cout << diff.count() << "h\n";

    diff = floor<hours>(zLondon->to_local(system_clock::now()) -
                      zNew_York->to_local(system_clock::now()));
    std::cout << diff.count() << "h\n";
}
```

Outputs today (2016/mar/28):

```
4h
5h
4h
```

For determining the local time in a zone that is not your computer's local time one can do this:

```
auto zLondon = locate_zone("Europe/London");
auto tp = zLondon->to_local(system_clock::now());
auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
weekday wd = dp;
year_month_day ymd = dp;
auto time = make_time(tp-dp);
```

`tp` is a "local" `std::chrono::time_point` shifted to the "Europe/London" timezone.

`dp` is the same type as `tp`, but with a precision of `days` instead of `microseconds` (or whatever).

`wd` is the current day of the week in London.

`ymd` is a year-month-day structure (with year, month and day getters) of the current time in London.

`time` is an hour-minute-second-subseconds structure (with those getters) marking the current London time.

This all could be used like this to find out if a market is open or not (this simplistic example code neglects holidays but takes weekends into account):

```
std::cout << "It is currently " << wd << ' ' << ymd << ' ' << time << '\n';
if (wd != sat && wd != sun && 9h <= time.hours() && time.hours() < 16h)
    std::cout << "Markets open\n";
else
    std::cout << "Markets closed\n";
```

This just output for me:

```
It is currently Thu 2016-03-31 16:39:15.656398
Markets closed
```

Comment: works perfectly. please know i try to not ask for such specific help and  i am very grateful when it is freely given.

Comment: @cjv:  You can communicate that this answer is the one that helped you most by "accepting" it.  This is done by clicking the checkmark just under the answer's score of votes.  Glad I could help.

Comment: done! my application is a multi-robotic trading system where one robot/thread needs to know if a certain market in London is open (opens at 9AM there) (already knowing if it is a weekday holiday there or not). thanks again, very nice person.

Comment: appreciate your going back and adding in the extra code. the issue i was dealing with has to be "common" among automated trading coders. i'd been improvising "system_time + 4/5 hours" in a config file but this was not robust to absent-mindedness.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is *"expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)"*

This doesn't always match London time. UK has daylight savings and their clock goes back and forth relative to UTC. Most other countries have their own daylight savings which are at different dates.

`GetLocalTime` gives the time in New York or whichever location you are at, with daylight savings adjustment.

Your program should use `GetSystemTime` everywhere.

When you want to show the date/time to user, use `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` for conversion.

```
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
GetSystemTime(&systemTime);

SYSTEMTIME localTime;
SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &systemTime, &localTime);
```

If you get user date/time input, use `TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime` to convert to UTC for internal program use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: Thanks, but when I read that earlier it appeared I would need to set my system's timezone to the other (London) time zone first, as it points in the system rather than accept a dynamic input.